# Filtering cells in pandas dataframe with unique row/column index pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pairwise

I have a NxN pandas dataframe with identical row and column names. Each element represents the pairwise distance between 2 objects with IDs identified by the row and column names (for instance in the 1st column, second row of the dataframe in the attached image, the distance between object 100 and object 1000 is 4407.97). However, half of these cells contain duplicate information because the distance between objects 1000 and 100 is listed in its own cell in the 1st row, 2nd column. Is there a computationally efficient way to retain only the cells with a unique row, column index pair?

*Example dataframe*
[image: Example dataframe]

I've tried to solve this with a loop that saves each index/row name combo in both directions as it loops (saving them in a list called "measured_pairs") and only saves a value in a vector called "pair_dist" if its index pair hasn't been looped over yet, but this is taking a very, very long time.

```
measured_pairs = []
pair_dist = []
for i in range(min_dists.shape[0]):
    rowname = min_dists.iloc[i].name
    colnames = min_dists.iloc[i].index.tolist()
    for col in colnames:
        if str(rowname) + '_' + str(col) in measured_pairs:
            pass
        elif rowname == col:
            pass
        else:
            pair_dist.append(min_dists[col].loc[rowname])
            measured_pairs.append(str(rowname) + '_' + str(col))
            measured_pairs.append(str(col) + '_' + str(rowname))
```

Comment: what is the expected output? You want to replace the duplicate values with nulls?

Comment: Your question is unclear, better provide a [mre] that demonstrates what is expected (input + expected output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame is symmetric and you're alright with converting to `numpy`:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((5,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(x, 
                  columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D","E"], 
                  index = ["A", "B", "C", "D","E"])

lower_triangular = np.tril(df.to_numpy())

lower_df = pd.DataFrame(lower_triangular, index = df.index, columns = df.columns)
```

Where what you're interested in is the upper (or lower) triangular matrix defined in `df`, and [`np.tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) is an efficient way of getting that matrix.

If your DataFrame is *not* symmetric, you'll need to first sort both the columns and the index identically, although based on your preview it *looks* like it's probably symmetric.